# Modifying XML file, replacement elements

Tags: c#, xml

I were trying use those code to Modify XML files in C#.

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"movies.xml");
    String target = textBox1.Text;

    var node = doc.Descendants("movie").FirstOrDefault(movie => movie.Element("title").Value == target);



    node.SetElementValue("title", this.textBox1.Text);
    node.SetElementValue("year", this.comboBox1.Text);

    Console.WriteLine(node);
    doc.Save(@"movies.xml");
```

the problem is: when I change 'year' element, everything works perfectly. However, when I change the title which I used as a keyword to search in XML file. The code does not do it in this way. Return a NULL error.

My XML file:

```
<movielist>
  <movie>
    <title>a movie name</title>
    <year>2015</year>
  </movie>
  <movie>
    <title>Another movie name</title>
    <year>2000</year>
  </movie>
</movielist>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you show your xml file? Also, what is actual error you're getting? "*Return a NULL error.*" is not a precise description of a problem. `SetElementValue` is `void` method, it doesn't returns anything, so try to describe your problem better.

Comment: I just update the XML file..   It shows a NullReferenceException Error when I change the title element..

Comment: Are you sure you're getting `NullReferenceException` at this line: `node.SetElementValue("title", this.textBox1.Text);`? From the first look - there are not so much options to get it here. It could be if `node` is null, or `textBox1` is null. Use a debugger and check it.

Comment: Ok, I gonna check it.  I am pretty sure the Error occurs at this time. other elements just always good when I gonna change them.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed.  String target should be out of the function( like put it in main). If not, It will always overwritten.